# How to type a generic function that returns subtypes

Tags: generics, flowtype

As per [flow's documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-generics-track-values-around), generics in flow tracks values around.

That means that this will raise an error:

```js
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // $ExpectError
    return '';
  }

  return value;
}
```

As far as I can tell, their documentation does not mention how to best type a function like this. Ideally you would want a to specify that the function returns a sub-type of the input type.

Specifically, I'd like to avoid those less safe typings:

```js
function identity<T>(value: T): (T | string) {
  ...
}
```

or

```js
function identity(value: mixed): mixed {
  ...
}
```

I've been puzzled by this mystery. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question! The best I can come up with is that your code seems correct and flow probably should support this case. In the meantime, you can cast to `any` before casting back to `T` so the function has the correct signature:

```
// Has the inferred signature `<T>(value: T) => T`
function identity<T>(value: T) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return ((value: any): T)
  }

  return value;
}
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKANwEMAbENALkXwEpEBvAKEWWEWJwAc0cbhWppEAXkmIA5AGcoAJxhgA5tObtOnBWiggFSYmSo165MNkb0mHRAF82tnXoOIRNANxs7QA))

Strangely enough, I also found that using `substr` on the value and annotating the return type as `T` can result in the `T => T` being accepted with no errors, despite it being essentially the same thing as returning `''` (?!?!)

```
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.substr(0,0)
  }

  return value;
}
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKANwEMAbENALkXwEp79EBvAKEWWEWJwAOaOLwrU0iALzTEAcgDOUAE4wwAc1mN2XboiVooIJUjE0AdPJAAjRUuIAGADT3GOgL4cd+w8cSm0ANwcbkA))

Maybe literal strings and dynamic ones are being treated differently under the hood, resulting in this odd difference in type handling?

From a pragmatic standpoint, it would be wise to add unit tests for the different cases this function is supposed to handle if you end up doing casting-magic.