# Trying to type return of generic Function [Flow]

Tags: flowtype

i'm want to create mapperFunction and type it return with generics;

But i'm catching an error;

Error - Cannot return `true` because boolean [1] is incompatible with `T` [2]

```
/* @flow */

const someMapper = <T>(param): T => {
    if (typeof param === 'boolean') {
      return true;
    }

    if (typeof param === 'string') {
      return 'string';
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

Working version, but without generics

```
const someMapper = (param): boolean | string | void => {
    if (typeof param === 'boolean') {
      return true;
    }

    if (typeof param === 'string') {
      return 'string';
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

[try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzFzgFsBTAWQEMAHGsgJzAF4wAeAFQD4AKGqhlRIBKAFxgOLLmADeqAJABLKGB74AnvTgr+gki2asA5ACM4cGGSrYjw2ajCOnDMvgCuDbGHwM3ZANwOTgC+QU7hYArKqhpaOgJCBsYEDIrYAOa29hFgLu6eYEYpaZmB4aEKeR5ebtgAJmRQaWR1gcFAA)

Comment: Generics might not actually be the best solution to this problem. What are you trying to accomplish at a higher level?

Comment: I'm equally confused by Flow with this and why it doesn't work for your examples. My own question from a while ago asks about this same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736465/how-does-flow-interpret-generic-types.

Comment: @user11307804 I went ahead and replied to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Flow interpret generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736465/how-does-flow-interpret-generic-types)